# Add a dynamic DropDownList to a Gridview (then export to excel)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I create a dynamic DropDownlist from code behind :

```
protected void test_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     DropDownList ddlSelection = new DropDownList();


     string value  = "";
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
         value = row.Field<String>("[First Row]");
     }
     List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
     mylist.Add("NORMAL");
     mylist.Add("LOW");

     ddlSelection.DataSource = mylist;
     ddlSelection.DataBind();
     ddlSelection.SelectedValue = value;
     e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(ddlSelection);
}
```

Then I export it to excel. Everything work fine expect the DropDownList which need to be placed inside the cell (cf: image below).

[image]

The DropDownList goes outside of its cell. How could I fix it please ?

Comment: how did you export the dropdownlist control to excel?

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Width = Unit.Pixel(200);
```

But I would like to make it dynamically. Is it possible to know the Width of the DropDownList ?

I tried this, but It doesn't work. The `ddlSelection.Width` Value = 0.

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Width = ddlSelection.Width;
```